# Traduire « One-stop Shop »

Tags: traduction

En anglais il y a le terme "One-stop shop" qui signifie un magasin pour tous besoins connexes.

Le plus près que j'ai trouvé est "Un guichet unique", mais je me demandais s'il y avait une  autre traduction généralement acceptée qui garde une connotation similaire.

Comment: Est-ce que tu peux préciser ce que tu entends par *tous besoins connexes* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Par exemple un magasin d'informatique, qui se veut offrir le plus besoin les besoins habituels autour du thème de l'informatique pour que le client n'ai pas besoin d'aller ailleurs quand il fait son achat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Guichet unique*** est l'expression utilisée en France pour désigner un endroit où un ensemble de services, en général administratifs et précédemment procurés à des endroits distincts, sont centralisés.

***One-stop shop*** semble souvent désigner exactement la même chose en anglais, mais il semble que ça peut aussi s'appliquer à un commerce où l'on peut trouver une grande variété d'articles. Dans ce dernier cas, on ne parle pas de *guichet unique*, mais de ***commerce multi-service*** (encore assez rare) ou peut-être simplement d'***épicerie du coin*** (où on trouve de tout). On disait autrefois ***bazar*** mais ce terme a évolué vers un sens péjoratif.

Comment: +1. Un "pôle de service de proximité" pourrait être une alternative au "guichet unique".

Comment: On trouve aussi au début du XX siècle et au Québec aussi je crois, magasin général.